# Error in parse - works in R Script, not in Markdown

Tags: r-markdown

I have an R Markdown document with code I was able to successfully run in an R script. When I knit it in markdown, I receive the error message:

> Quitting from lines 22-24 (PalmerPenguins.Rmd)
> Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src) : :2:46: unexpected '='
> 1: ggplot(data = penguins) + geom_point(mapping = aes(x = body_mass_g, y = flipper_length_mm)+
> 2:                                        color =
> ^
> Calls:  ...  -> parse_all -> parse_all.character -> parse
> Execution halted

Here is the text of the document:

````
---
title: "ggplot_hook"
author: "Bill"
date: "2023-03-13"
output: html_document
---

## Setting up my environment  
Notes: setting up my R environment by loading the 'tidyverse' and 'palmer penguins' packages  

```{r loading packages}
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)
```

## Visualizations
Here we will go through a series of visualizations

### Flipper and body mass in purple
Here, we plot flipper length against body mass
```{r visualize flipper and body mass in purple}
ggplot(data = penguins) + geom_point(mapping = aes(x = body_mass_g, y = flipper_length_mm)+
                                       color = "purple")
```

### Flipper and body mass by species
Here, we plot flipper length against body mass and we look at breakdown by species

```{r species}
ggplot(data = penguins, aes(x = body_mass_g, y = flipper_length_mm)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=species))
```

### Flipper and body mass by species and sex
Here, we plot flipper length against body mass and look at the breakdown by species and sex

```{r species and sex}
ggplot(data = penguins, aes(x = body_mass_g, y = flipper_length_mm)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=species, color=sex), )
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch the `+` to a `,` before `color = "purple"`:

````
```{r visualize flipper and body mass in purple}
ggplot(data = penguins) + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = body_mass_g, y = flipper_length_mm),
                                       color = "purple")
```
````